# Function classes as a comparator

Tags: c++, templates

1) If I want the set to store elements in descending order, I could write:

```
set<int, greater<int>> s;
```

but i can also

```
set<int, greater<>> s;
```

how does the compiler understand this?

2) Why in the following case

```
vector<int> a;
binary_search(a.begin(), a.end(), 5, greater<>());
```

I have to write **greater<>()**, instead of **greater<>**. This has some reason why it could not be done the same everywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) how does the compiler understand this?

Because since C++14, the template parameter `T` of [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) has a default value `void`; then `std::greater<>` is just the same as `std::greater<void>`.

> The standard library provides a specialization of `std::greater` when `T` is not specified, which leaves the parameter types and return type to be deduced.

and

> 2) This has some reason why it could not be done the same everywhere?

Because `binary_search` is a function and expects its argument as object. `greater<>` (i.e. `greater<void>`) is a ***type***, while `greater<>()` is an ***object*** (which is a temporary object in context of `binary_search(a.begin(), a.end(), 5, greater<>());`).

BTW: In `set<int, greater<>> s;`, you're specifying `greater<>` as the template argument. The 2nd template parameter of [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is a [type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Type_template_parameter)
, then it's fine to specify `greater<>` (which is a ***type***) as the template argument.